# How to call Dialog Class From a LUIS Intent

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using Bot Framework V4 dispatch model to invoke LUIS and QnA services.
I can call the code inside of the top scoring intents class.

However, I couldn't find a way to call an external dialog from it. How can I do that?

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

    namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
    {
        public class DispatchBot : ActivityHandler
        {
            private ILogger<DispatchBot> _logger;
            private IBotServices _botServices;

            public DispatchBot(IBotServices botServices, ILogger<DispatchBot> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _botServices = botServices;
            }

            protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
                var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

                // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
                var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

                // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
                await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
            }

            protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                const string WelcomeText = "Type a greeting, or a question about the weather to get started.";

                foreach (var member in membersAdded)
                {
                    if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Welcome to Dispatch bot {member.Name}. {WelcomeText}"), cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }

            private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                switch (intent)
                {
                    case "l_HomeAutomation":
                        //WANT TO CALL THE EXTERNAL DIALOG CLASS FROM HERE
                        //await ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                        break;
                    case "l_Weather":
                        await ProcessWeatherAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                        break;
                    case "q_sample-qna":
                        await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                        break;
                    default:
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}."), cancellationToken);
                        break;
                }
            }

            private async Task ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, LuisResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("ProcessHomeAutomationAsync");

                // Retrieve LUIS result for Process Automation.
                var result = luisResult.ConnectedServiceResult;
                var topIntent = result.TopScoringIntent.Intent; 

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"HomeAutomation top intent {topIntent}."), cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"HomeAutomation intents detected:\n\n{string.Join("\n\n", result.Intents.Select(i => i.Intent))}"), cancellationToken);
                if (luisResult.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"HomeAutomation entities were found in the message:\n\n{string.Join("\n\n", result.Entities.Select(i => i.Entity))}"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }

            private async Task ProcessWeatherAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, LuisResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("ProcessWeatherAsync");

                // Retrieve LUIS results for Weather.
                var result = luisResult.ConnectedServiceResult;
                var topIntent = result.TopScoringIntent.Intent;
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"ProcessWeather top intent {topIntent}."), cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"ProcessWeather Intents detected::\n\n{string.Join("\n\n", result.Intents.Select(i => i.Intent))}"), cancellationToken);
                if (luisResult.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"ProcessWeather entities were found in the message:\n\n{string.Join("\n\n", result.Entities.Select(i => i.Entity))}"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }

            private async Task ProcessSampleQnAAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("ProcessSampleQnAAsync");

                var results = await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
                if (results.Any())
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system."), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to initialize instances of the required dialogs in your DispatchBot, and then invoke them like this:
`await this.weatherDialog.RunAsync(turnContext, dialogStateAccessor, cancellationToken)`

Here is [some sample code](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot/blob/master/zyin.intentbot/Bot/DialogBot.cs). It's slightly different from your design since I am delegating intent detection to a parent dialog and then do the logic branching from there (to keep the bot class logic simple), but how to invoke dialogs is the same.

Update based on discussion below:
If you are using multi turn dialogs, I would suggest you follow the pattern in my code. Otherwise you'll have to deal dialog continue by yourself and good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
It partially worked.
Now the code calls the dialog according to the LUIS intent but after the user reply it falls out of the DialogSet. 
The problem is when the conversation flows back to the DispachDialog class it doesn't know the actual intent and hence doesn't resume the flow to the next step of the waterfall process.
How I can avoid this to happen?
Call code excerpt:
...                
`case "l_HomeAutomation":
      await _dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
      break;`

Comment: So you have "multi turn" dialogs. In that case that's exactly why I had the intent detection in a parent dialog and start sub dialogs from there. It's your responsibility to resume on the same "dialog stack" when you start different dialogs from the bot class.
In my sample code you don't have to worry about this since it's always resuming on the parent dialog and the parent dialog knows which child dialog to resume on with the dialog stack built in.

Comment: Fair enough my friend. Let me have a closer look at your sample code next. ;) Thx

Comment: Sure thing. Just to be clear, it’s not an idea I invented. I took it by learning from the official samples and the community. I do have something in my repo extra to make certain things much easier though.

Comment: Help really appreciated. Looking from a botframework V3 it seems the V4 became more complicated to program and less straight forward. In this case all I'd need would just need a simple await context.Forward to start a new dialog.  Jesus Christ Microsoft! Anyway, how can I add a Qna service call to your framework? Thought about creating a Qna service and then SampleFallbackHandler has been trigged. Woudl that work? Thx

Comment: @AmintasLopesNeto - yes. The FallbackHandler is meant to provide some answer as a "catch all" thing to the user with the intent not known by the bot - e.g. a Google search. QnA seems like a good usage of it as well.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification and help!